# Docker-compose: Use gelf driver can not resolve host of linked container

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I´m trying to redirect the logs produced by my containers to another container holding ELK but I get this error:

```
ERROR: for uid-manager  Failed to initialize logging driver: gelf: cannot connect to GELF endpoint: elk_stack:12201 dial udp: lookup elk_stack: no such host
```

This is my configuration:

```
version: '2'
services:
   elk_stack:
     image: sebp/elk
     container_name: elk_stack
     ports:
      - "5601:5601"
      - "9200:9200"
      - "12201:12201/udp"
     expose:
      - "5601"
      - "9200"
      - "12201/udp"
   uid-manager:
     image: uid-manager-server:latest
     container_name: uid-manager
     ports:
      - "15100:15100"
      - "9111:9111"
     expose:
      - "15100"
      - "9111"
     logging:
      driver: gelf
      options:
       gelf-address: "udp://elk_stack:12201"
     environment:
      - [...]
     links:
      - elk_stack
```

Could you please tell what am I doing wrong? Thanks!

Comment: It might be a docker issue. https://github.com/docker/docker/issues/20370 I have the same problem and used the IP address as a workaround.